# android toolbar not working properly

Tags: java, android, layout, toolbar

I've set up a toolbar in one of my application's activities, but it crashes everytime I try to go to said activity. Maybe I'm missing something? Can someone help me out with this? Haven't used toolbar before so still a little confused.

Here's the code of activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProjectCreateScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondary_layout1);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.AwesomeBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle the menu item
            return true;
        }
    });
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);


    final TextView noProject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NOPROJECT);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

    final ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    final ListAdapter addAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item, R.id.listFrame, listItems);
    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setAdapter(addAdapter);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            noProject.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listItems.add("New Project");
            ((ArrayAdapter) addAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent switchToEdit = new Intent(ProjectCreateScreen.this,
                    teamCreateScreen.class);
            startActivity(switchToEdit);
        }
    });
}
```

And the xml file the activity uses:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rl">

<android.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/AwesomeBar"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    </android.widget.Toolbar>

<Button
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/addBtn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AwesomeBar"
    android:background="@drawable/add_greyslate"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/noProjectsNotice"
    android:id="@+id/NOPROJECT"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addBtn"
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:visibility="invisible">
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: nothing on logcat, It just says that the application stopped working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your XML file replace:

```
 <android.widget.Toolbar
```

with:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Because in your code you are referring to support version.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved it, although when first setting up the toolbar i haven't seen the support.v7 version at all in the dropdown menu. Also was it a good idea to swap it with the ActionBar? I feel like it's somewhat easier to manage

Comment: @Richard Without diving into details - if you need more control over your `ActionBar` - `Toolbars` come in handy.